# List of Boxes Detail

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, mdframed

I was wondering if someone knows how to "tell" LaTeX to print an Index of Boxes ("Recuadros" for me), in a similar way to the regular Index of Tables. In the last case there is an extra space between tables from different sections, something I have been unable to to in the case of boxes.

The way I am doing the boxes is first to define the style and then the numbering for the boxes (using `mdframed`):
  ....

```
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
    nobreak,    
    linecolor=blue,
    outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
    roundcorner=20pt,
    innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=20pt,
    innerleftmargin=20pt,
    frametitlealignment=\center,
    backgroundcolor=gray!30!white}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcounter{infobox}
\newenvironment{infobox}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{infobox}%
\begin{mdframed}[%
style=MyFrame,
frametitle={Recuadro \theinfobox\ #1},
]%
\addcontentsline{lob}{section}{\numberline{\theinfobox}#1}%
}{%
\end{mdframed}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listboxname{Índice de recuadros}
\newcommand\listofboxes{
\chapter*{\listboxname}
\@starttoc{lob}
}
\renewcommand{\theinfobox}{\thechapter.\arabic{infobox}}
\makeatother
....
```

The way LaTeX prints the results for tables and boxes are:

[image]

You can see there is an extra space between tables from different chapters which is what I am trying to do for the boxes.

Comment: This requires adding code to the `\chapter` command and this depends on the used documentclass. Side comment: You're using `tocloft` already, which provides 'easier' ways to define such `\listof...` commands ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution for the `book` class: Modifying `\@chapter` slightly to add automatically vertical spacing to the `.lob` file after each `\chapter` starts.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
    nobreak,    
    linecolor=blue,
    outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
    roundcorner=20pt,
    innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=20pt,
    innerleftmargin=20pt,
    frametitlealignment=\center,
    backgroundcolor=gray!30!white}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\newcounter{infobox}[chapter]
\newenvironment{infobox}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{infobox}%
  \begin{mdframed}[%
    style=MyFrame,
    frametitle={Recuadro \theinfobox\ #1},
    ]%
    \addcontentsline{lob}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theinfobox~}#1}%
  }{%
  \end{mdframed}
}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \chaptermark{#1}%
}{
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \addtocontents{lob}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}{\typeout{success}}{}


%
\newcommand\listboxname{Índice de recuadros}
\newcommand\listofboxes{%
  \chapter*{\protect\listboxname}
  \@starttoc{lob}
}
\renewcommand{\theinfobox}{\thechapter.\arabic{infobox}}
\makeatother




\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofboxes
\listoffigures
\chapter{First}
\begin{infobox}[Some box]
  And now for something completely different
\end{infobox}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{second}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{second}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{second}
\end{figure}


\chapter{Second}
\begin{infobox}[Some box]
  And now for something completely different
\end{infobox}

\begin{infobox}[Some box]
  And now for something completely different
\end{infobox}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{second}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Christian, unfortunately it is still throwing the output in same way. Could it be because I am using "LaTex + Bib(la) tex + LaTex (x2) + dvip + ps2pdf + Ver PDF"?

Comment: @Fernando: I would say: **No** -- it's perhaps a different document class, but you did not say which class you're using. I asked you already in a comment below your question, but you did not give feedback to it :-(

Comment: I am sorry Christian. I forgot that. What I am using is: "\documentclass[twoside]{book}". Thank you very much!

Comment: @Fernando: I've used `book` too, I don't know what breaks in your case.